# Webpack UglifyJsPlugin Error when nonuse sourceMap

Tags: javascript

I know [UglifyJsPlugin do not support ES6](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/#components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx), so there has some problems when ES6 transform to ES5

In production env
Error: **Unexpected token punc «,», expected punc «:» [bundle.js:2808,8]**

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    output: {
        comments: false
    }
})
```

But It's OK In development env

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    sourceMap: true,
    output: {
        comments: false
    }
})
```

Webpack v2.4.1 and babel v6.5.2
Webpack presets: ["es2015","stage-0","react"]

The screenshot of error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcZJz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the code what I post is not ES6, while it follow the CMD principle.
That code Webpack will not transform and UglifyJsPlugin can't transform.